error CS0535: 'NetMQPublisher' does not implement interface member 'IProcessor.Process(Component_Animation)
I am new to C#.I had never encountered any issues when opening my Unity project before, but one day, when I tried to open it, I encountered the following error. I couldn't find any relevant solutions online.
I tried reinstalling Unity and switching versions, but nothing worked.
So, I wanted to ask if anyone else has faced the same issue, or if someone knows how to fix it?

Assets\Plugins\CodeAssist\Editor\NetMQPublisher.cs(30,35): error CS0535: 'NetMQPublisher' does not implement interface member 'IProcessor.Process(Component_Animation)'
Assets\Plugins\CodeAssist\Editor\NetMQPublisher.cs(30,35): error CS0535: 'NetMQPublisher' does not implement interface member 'IProcessor.Process(Component_Animator)'
Assets\Plugins\CodeAssist\Editor\NetMQPublisher.cs(30,35): error CS0535: 'NetMQPublisher' does not implement interface member 'IProcessor.Process(RequestUpdate)'

This is the interface:
    public class NetMQPublisher : Synchronizer.Model.IProcessor
    {
        PublisherSocket? pubSocket;
        readonly string pubConnString;

        Task? pullTask;
        CancellationTokenSource? pullTaskCancellationTokenSource;

        readonly Synchronizer.Model.Manager syncMngr;

        public List<Synchronizer.Model.Connect> clients;

        Synchronizer.Model.Connect? _self;

        Synchronizer.Model.Connect Self => _self!;

        void InitializeSelf()
        {
            var projectPath = CommonTools.GetProjectPath();
            _self = new Synchronizer.Model.Connect()
            {
                ModelVersion = Synchronizer.Model.Utilities.Version,
                ProjectPath = projectPath,
                ProjectName = getProjectName(),
                ContactInfo = $"Unity {Application.unityVersion}",
                AssemblyVersion = Assister.Version,
            };

            string getProjectName()
            {
                string[] s = projectPath.Split('/');
                string projectName = s[s.Length - 2];
                //Logg("project = " + projectName);
                return projectName;
            }
        }


You should reach out to the asset creator, its their product they should support it

I actually figured it out!
Visual Studio added this folder and it's existence was breaking mine with the same errors:
Assets\Plugins\CodeAssist
I just deleted that "CodeAssist" folder and everything went back to normal!!
